# Makefile for AppJS

Tags: appjs

The current [AppJS](http://appjs.org) project does not contain a makefile for Windows. Has anyone already created a makefile for Windows compilation?

If I add the files from "src" to an empty project in Visual Studio I have many missing references to NodeJS, such as node.h.

If I can either get a makefile to utilize with Mozilla's Build Setup that is recommended in the building.md file or a Visual Studio project that would be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look in the docs directory of appjs (https://github.com/appjs/appjs/blob/master/docs/building.md) then there is a short description of how to compile using MozillaBuild.

I have also added a more detailed description of getting appjs to compile on windows using the free Microsoft Visual Studio C++ 2010 Express: https://github.com/sihorton/appjs/blob/master/docs/building.md.

Hopefully the second link gives you enough to get started with.

/Simon